# Galaxy Note 10.1, does not recognize finger touch

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have a Galaxy Note 10.1, It suddenly stopped (when switched on) finger touch detection, but works with normally with S Pen. I tried Factory resetting but still it does not detect finger touch... I tried to find any setting regarding finger touch but I couldn't. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How long have you had your Note for before it started doing this?

Comment: @Denny After about a week... :(, After another two weeks time it worked normally.. :)

Comment: If you have the Samsung Book Cover, try closing it (which turns off the screen) and opening it. The screen should turn on again and finger touch will work again. You can also do this by holding a magnet to the sides of the screen (the book cover has little magnets in it). This solved the problem for me instantly, where previously only the S-Pen worked but not my fingers. For some reason I cannot add this as an answer even though I have more than 100 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `settings`, then `language` and `input`, then `Samsung keyboard settings`, then `handwriting`, then `recognition time`. Try changing it and then try touching. Sometimes this could solve. Also try touching the 4 corners.

Comment: I tried changing `Recognition Time` but no avail. :( , What do you mean by touching 4 corners? Anyway thanks for the answer...

Comment: Since Note 10.1 is auto calibrated,touching the four corners of the screen will do some help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ii7m2696T3Y) describes an issue that could be related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let it run dead to the point where it won't turn on, charge it till full (without using it at all) turn it back on and it should. Be fine. Happened to me. :)